# AS3 Reference subClass of subClass from parent without instantiating?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, subclass

Can I access a static variable of a subClass' subClass? I don't want to instantiate it, just looking to get the variable because it has already been initialized by the subClass.

example:

```
package
{
    public class A extends MovieClip {
        private var classB:B = new B();

        public function A() {
            //**ACCESS B.C.MYVAR**
        }
    }
}

package
{
    public class B extends MovieClip {
        private var classC:C = new C();
    }
}

package
{
    public class C extends MovieClip {

        public static var MYVAR = 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a **public static** var you can do so from anywhere within the same package via Class.property.

So to access MYVAR that's defined in Class C, you would use C.MYVAR.

You don't need to create an instance of a class to access static properties or functions within it - so long as they are public.

I don't recommend using **static** except for in rare cases such as a "utilities" class or something similar. A good example is the Math class that's inbuilt.

I mostly use static in a class that holds constants, like this example:

```
package
{
    public class Elements
    {
        public static const FIRE:String = "FIRE_ELEMENT";
        public static const WATER:String = "WATER_ELEMENT";
        public static const ICE:String = "ICE_ELEMENT";
    }
}
```

Then later I make use of this like so:

```
var myelement:String = Elements.WATER;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marty, what about calling a public var from C that is not static? Is this possible? What I have is an event dispatched from B to let me know that C changed but I need to retrieve the variable in C from A when the event is dispatched. Man I hope you can make sense of what I just wrote.

Comment: @Tim Joyce do you still want the question in your comment answered?

Answer (score 1):

An answer has already been accepted for this question but my answer is in response to the question asked by Tim Joyce in his comment for the accepted answer:

> Thanks for the answer Marty, what
>   about calling a public var from C that
>   is not static? Is this possible? What
>   I have is an event dispatched from B
>   to let me know that C changed but I
>   need to retrieve the variable in C
>   from A when the event is dispatched.
>   Man I hope you can make sense of what
>   I just wrote.

The following is a small flash application I created to answer that question:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _popcornMicrowave:PopcornMicrowave;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            // 1 minute and 30 seconds
            var delay:Number = PopcornMicrowave.MINUTE + (PopcornMicrowave.SECOND * 30);

            _popcornMicrowave = new PopcornMicrowave(delay);

            trace(_popcornMicrowave.popcorn.isReady); // output: false

            _popcornMicrowave.startTimer();

            _popcornMicrowave.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPopcornMicrowaveComplete);

        }// end function

        private function onPopcornMicrowaveComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            _popcornMicrowave.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPopcornMicrowaveComplete);

            trace(_popcornMicrowave.popcorn.isReady) // output: true

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

internal class PopcornMicrowave extends EventDispatcher
{
    public static const SECOND:Number = 1000;
    public static const MINUTE:Number = SECOND * 60;

    private var _popcorn:Popcorn;
    private var _timer:Timer;

    public function get popcorn():Popcorn { return _popcorn }

    public function PopcornMicrowave(delay:Number = MINUTE) 
    { 
        _popcorn = new Popcorn();
        _timer = new Timer(delay, 1);

    }// end function

    public function startTimer():void
    {
        if (!_timer.running)
        {
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
            _timer.start(); 

        }// end if

    }// end function

    private function onTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);

        _popcorn.setIsReady(true);

        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class Popcorn
{
    private var _isReady:Boolean;

    public function get isReady():Boolean { return _isReady }

    public function Popcorn() { }

    internal function setIsReady(boolean:Boolean):void 
    { 
        _isReady = boolean 

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Answer (score 1):

A static variable can easily be referenced from anywhere. Whether it'd be a super-class accessing one of it's subclass (or sub-sub-...-class), or a completely different class dependent on the static variable in question, you can access it this way:

```
public function someFunction():void {
  //Direct Access: Most typical way - accessing a public static var / const,
  //your local-variable should match the data-type of the static
  //variable you're accessing.
  var localVar:String = ClassName.StaticVarName;

  //Dynamic Access: An alternative that can be handy for verifying
  //variables that exists, and then use them once confirmed:
  if(ClassName["StaticVarName"]!=null) {
     trace("Found value: " + ClassName["StaticVarName"]);
  }

  //Iterative Access: If you're looking to iterate through each static
  //variables of a certain class, you can collect those by accessing its
  //description XML document (E4X access that is).
  var classDescription:XML = describeType(ClassName);
  var classVarNames:XMLList =    classDescription.variable.attribute("name");
  for each(var classVarName:String in classVarNames) {
     trace("Found class var: " + classVarName);
  }
}
```

Now, in order to access instance variables buried a few levels down in your Class hierarchy, you can try something like this:

```
// File: A.as
package {
    public class A {
        public function A() {

        }

        public function doSomething():void {
            switch(Object(this).constructor) {
                case B: trace( B(this).methodOnlyInB() ); break;
                case C: trace( C(this).variableOnlyInC ); break;
                default: trace("You are simply in 'A'!"); break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// File: B.as
package {
    public class B extends A {
        public function B() {
            super();
        }

        public function methodOnlyInB():String {
            return "You are calling a 'B' method!";
        }
    }
}

// File: C.as
package {
    public class C extends B {
        public var variableOnlyInC:String = "You are tracing a 'C' variable";

        public function C() {
            super();
        }
    }
}

// File: TestABC.as
var a:A = new A();
var b:B = new B();
var c:C = new C();

a.doSomething();  //Should trace: You are simply in 'A'!
b.doSomething();  //Should trace: You are calling a 'B' method!
c.doSomething();  //Should trace: You are tracing a 'C' variable!
```

There is one bit of "issue" going down this route. This will make you write "poor code". A Super-Class should **NOT** know any of it's sub-classes business and what they should do under certain conditions. Its a rule that pretty much every programming design pattern try to encourage (and for good reasons), and violating this rule can cost a lot of time, energy and hair-pulling in the long run.

Situations like this calls for a "*Controller*" class. Basically a class, instantiated from elsewhere will have the responsibility to analyze the A/B/C object (ex: similarly to how A.doSomething()'s switch statement does this). This frees up your Super & Sub classes from clutter and leaves much more room for expansion and solid code.

Hope this answers all your variable access needs! :)

Comment: Thanks bigp. This will definitely help in my constant quest to write leaner, meaningful code. I will be googling for some source code of controllers.

Comment: No problem Tim! To avoid sending you off on a wild-goose-chase (or wild-google-chase in this case), the term Controller is most often used in the MVC Design pattern, but in this context I was referring mostly to an additional class that is in charge of interpreting the "instance is A, instance is B, etc." scenarios. This interpretation could also just performed inside a static method in a separate class, not necessarily in a instance-method of this separate class.